# Save excel formulas in database and be able to use them later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

Users will be able to [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) Excel Formulas in my database like the one below:

```
cta/12*1.33%
```

Where *cta* will be a value later. I believe the best way to store them is as simple strings.

**How can I transform this formula in a calculation?**

To use like this:

```
cta = 10
result = cta/12*1.33%
```

I know about `eval('cta/12*1.33')`, but since my users will type the formulas themselves, I don't think is very safe to use *eval*.

**Is there another option?**

Comment: Perhaps try googling [parse excel formula ruby](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=parse+excel+formula+ruby&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)? There looks to be one or two interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a *solution*.

Instead of letting the user type the formula, we will give user the operations he can put. More like a calculator but blocking the typing.